# Line Numbers in PHP Storm

Tags: php, numbers, line, permanent

How do I permanently turn on line numbers in PHP Storm? I can put them on for my current file using the view menu but they don't seem to stay on for other windows.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

> Settings > Editor > General > Appearance

there, enable "**Show line numbers**"

Settings can be displayed with CTRL+MAJ+S

Answer (score 1):

Settings or Preferences if your are on Mac | Editor | (General) | Appearance | Show line numbers

Ctrl + Shift + A on Windows lets you search all options. Just hit it and type line numbers and you can enable and disable them